# Error installing linux-image-5.15.0.89-generic on 20.04

Tags: 20.04

There are unmet dependencies. I then run:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.15.0-89-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-hwe-5.15-source-5.15.0 linux-hwe-5.15-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.15.0-89-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 11.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 233653 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.15.0-89-generic_5.15.0-89.99~20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.15.0-89-generic (5.15.0-89.99~20.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.15.0-89-generic_5.15.0-89.99~20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-89-generic.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.15.0-89-generic_5.15.0-89.99~20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: Do you have antivirus software running??

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks so much for your help Artur! Greatly appreciated!!